# Collect data in main program, then run an external program to process collected data and use result to plot in main

Tags: python, import, subprocess, store, collect

I am developing a program to be the user interface that collects data and then use an external program to process it, finally, fetch the results back to plot them in main.
My problem is that I cannot manage to use a proper import function without falling into a loop.

For simplicity reasons, I will create a dummy code that represents what I am doing and my problem:

main.py

```
import sys,os, math, statistics, re
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue,Pipe
import subprocess

'''---Data input block---'''

print('-----Welcome to mainX-----')
num1=int(input('type number 1:'))
num2=int(input('type number 2:'))

print('choose a tool between adding and multiplying')
tool=input('multiply/add: ')

'''---Data storage block---'''

class Input:

    def __init__(self, point_a, point_b):
        self.data_a=num1
        self.data_b=num2

    def data_a(self):
        return(self.data_a)

    def data_b(self):
        return(self.data_b)

'''---external program block---'''

if tool == 'add':
     Add= subprocess.run(['python',"add.py"], capture_output=True)

if tool == 'multiply':
     Multiply= subprocess.run(['python',"multiply.py"], capture_output=True)

'''---Plotting block---'''

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7,5))
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)

TK = np.linspace(1,10)

if tool == add:
   ax.plot(TK, addresult, label='This is te result of addition', c='g', linewidth=3)

if tool == multiply:
       ax.plot(TK, multiplyresult, label='This is te result of multiplying', c='g', linewidth=3)



ax.set_xlim(270, 400)
plt.legend(fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Add.py

```
from main import data_a

addresult:[data_a +1, data_a +2, data_a +3]
```

Multiply.py

```
from main import data_b
multiplyresult: [data_b *1, data_b *2, data_b *3]
```

Disclaimer: There are clearly some errors in this dummy code, but I just wanted to illustrate the general flow.

The errors I am getting are:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'data_a' from 'main'
```

or just going into an infinite loop asking for the input data

Thanks for the help!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: there is no `data_a` in `main.py` - there is only `self.data_a` inside class `Input` but it is useless for you. You can't run other script and `import` data created in current running program. `import` loads only code from file `main` but it can't get data which running program created in memory. You have to save data in file and read it from file in other script. OR you should import `Add` to `main` and run function directly - and then you could use data directly.

Comment: in class when you define `def data_a(...)` then it creates variable `self.data_a` to access this function inside other functions - but you use `self.data_a` also to keep value `self.data_a=num1` so one of this variables can be deleted.

Comment: you should keep code in functions because when you `import main` then it runs code which is not inside function.

Comment: you defined class `Input` but you never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code you have many mistakes.

There are no `data_a`, `data_b` but `self.data_a`, `self.data_b`.

You created class `Input` but you never created instances like

```
data = Input(num1, num2)
```

to keep data in this class.

But all this is useless because `self.data_a` `self.data_a` are created dynamically in memory when you run `main.py` but `import main` can load only code from file `main.py` - it can't get data created when `main` was running. You would have to save data in file and other script would have to read from file. OR you would have to send it as argument in command line `run(['python',"multiply.py", str(num1)]` and other script would have to use `sys.argv[1]` to get it. And script has to use `print()` to send result back to `main` (`subprocess`). And `main` would have to read this string, split to separated numbers and convert to integer - so it would need a lot work.

There is also other problem. When you import `main` then it runs all code in this file which is not in functions - so you have loop which ask again for inputs.

I would do it in different way. I would put code in functions in `Add.py`, `Multiply.py` and I would `import Add, Multiply` in `main`. And this way I could run it without `subprocess`

Something like this

Add.py

```
def add(data):
    return [data+1, data+2, data+3]
```

Multiply.py

```
def multiply(data)
    return [data*1, data*2, data*3]
```

main.py

```
import sys  # PEP8: imports in separated lines
import os
import math
import statistics
import re

from Add import add
from Multiply import multiply

# --- classes ---

class Input:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.a = b

    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

    def get_b(self):
        return self.b

# --- functions ---

def main():
    # ---Data input block---
    
    print('-----Welcome to mainX-----')
    num1 = int(input('type number 1:'))  # PEP8: spaces aroung `=`
    num2 = int(input('type number 2:'))
    
    print('choose a tool between adding and multiplying')
    tool = input('multiply/add: ')
    
    # ---Data storage block---
    
    data = Input(num1, num2)
    
    # ---external program block---
    
    if tool == 'add':
         result = add(data.get_a())
    
    if tool == 'multiply':
         result = multiply(data.get_b())
    
    # ---Plotting block---
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))  
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    
    TK = np.linspace(1,10)
    
    if tool == 'add':
        ax.plot(TK, result, label='This is te result of addition', c='g', linewidth=3)
    
    if tool == 'multiply':
        ax.plot(TK, result, label='This is te result of multiplying', c='g', linewidth=3)
    
    ax.set_xlim(270, 400)
    plt.legend(fontsize=14)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**EDIT:**

With `subprocess` it could look like this

Add.py

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1
    data = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(data+1, data+2, data+3)
```

Multiply.py

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1
    data = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(data*1, data*2, data*3)
```

main.py

```
import sys  # PEP8: imports in separated lines
import os
import math
import statistics
import re
import subprocess

# --- classes ---

class Input:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.a = b

    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

    def get_b(self):
        return self.b

# --- functions ---

def main():
    # ---Data input block---
    
    print('-----Welcome to mainX-----')
    num1 = int(input('type number 1:'))  # PEP8: spaces aroung `=`
    num2 = int(input('type number 2:'))
    
    print('choose a tool between adding and multiplying')
    tool = input('multiply/add: ')
    
    # ---Data storage block---
    
    data = Input(num1, num2)
    
    # ---external program block---
    
    if tool == 'add':
         p = subprocess.run(['python', 'Add.py', str(data.get_a())])
    
    if tool == 'multiply':
         p = subprocess.run(['python', 'Multiply.py', str(data.get_b())])
    
    output = p.stdout
    result = [int(value) for value in output.split(' ')]

    # ---Plotting block---
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))  
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    
    TK = np.linspace(1,10)
    
    if tool == 'add':
        ax.plot(TK, result, label='This is te result of addition', c='g', linewidth=3)
    
    if tool == 'multiply':
        ax.plot(TK, result, label='This is te result of multiplying', c='g', linewidth=3)
    
    ax.set_xlim(270, 400)
    plt.legend(fontsize=14)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This is exactly what I was looking for but wasn't aware of the details. For some reason, I couldn't get the subprocess version to run, but the first method works perfectly. I just fixed some details that I am going to post in case anyone wants to use it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by [@furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas), the best way to make this work is to save the inputs in main, **define methods in the external scripts and then import them to main** to use them with the input information.
You can save the result in main as well, then use it for whatever you want. Like plotting.

To complement the code written by [@furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) and make it fully functional I made some small adjustments:

**Add.py**

```
def add(data):
    return [data+1, data+2, data+3]
```

---

**Multiply.py**

```
def multiply(data):
    return [data*1, data*2, data*3]
```

---

**main.py**

```
import sys  # PEP8: imports in separated lines
import os
import math
import statistics
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from Add import add
from Multiply import multiply


# --- classes ---

class Input:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

    def get_b(self):
        return self.b

# --- functions ---

def main():
    # ---Data input block---

    print('-----Welcome to mainX-----')
    num1 = int(input('type number 1:'))  # PEP8: spaces aroung `=`
    num2 = int(input('type number 2:'))

    print('choose a tool between adding and multiplying')
    tool = input('multiply/add: ')

    # ---Data storage block---

    data = Input(num1, num2)

    # ---external program block---

    if tool == 'add':
         result = add(data.get_a())

    if tool == 'multiply':
         result = multiply(data.get_b())

    # ---Plotting block---

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    if tool == 'add':
        ax.plot(result, label='This is the result of addition', c='r', linewidth=3)

    if tool == 'multiply':
        ax.plot(result, label='This is the result of multiplying', c='g', linewidth=3)

    plt.legend(fontsize=14)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```